# Where can I watch the announcement from LIGO about gravitational waves?

Tags: gravitational-waves

Today the LIGO consortium are having a press conference to update us on their search for gravitational waves. How should I watch the announcement?

Comment: APOD has the critical matching pair of squiggly lines here: http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap160211.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event will be live streamed on youtube here: https://www.youtube.com/user/VideosatNSF/live

The will also be tweeting: https://twitter.com/ligo

A video of the conference will also be available afterwards if you miss it. It starts at 10:30 EST, which is 3:30 GMT.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest place: https://www.youtube.com/user/VideosatNSF/live, or alternatively it will probably be on most news websites.